# Create Associative array with ArrayCollection::map

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

**TL;DR: Why does Doctrine's ArrayCollection only supports mapping an array without setting a key?**

I want to create an associative array (key->value) from my Doctrine entities: i.e. `customerId => CustomerName`, `userId => userName`, etc. Creating an associative array isn't rocket science, so there are many other ways to achieve this.

However, I'm still wondering why `ArrayCollection:map` (or a similar method) doesn't have an option to do this. Creating an array with keys is support by it's constructor method and `ArrayCollection::set()`. You can even create an array like this:

```
$arraycollection = new ArrayCollection();
$arraycollection->add('John Doe');
$arraycollection->set('foo', 'bar');
$arraycollection->set(418, 'teapot');
```

But you can't set keys with `ArrayCollection::map()`. Why? Am I the first developer that is looking for a feature like this (not very likely) or am I missing an important principle that makes it unnecessary, impossible, undesireable or a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this answer Adam Wathan's blog **[Customizing Keys When Mapping Collections](https://adamwathan.me/2016/07/14/customizing-keys-when-mapping-collections/)**:

> This problem of wanting to customize keys during a map operation is
>   something I get asked about pretty regularly.
>
> I think the reason it seems like a tricky problem is because in PHP,
>   we use the same data type to represent both a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) and a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(data_structure)).

He uses Laravel’s Collection library:

```
$emailLookup = $employees->reduce(function ($emailLookup, $employee) {
    $emailLookup[$employee['email']] = $employee['name'];
    return $emailLookup;
}, []);
```

That's exactly the solution I would like to use, but it isn't in Doctrine's ArrayCollection. A [pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/pull/16) to add a reduce() method has been closes because of backwards compatibility.

Thanks to [this example](https://gist.github.com/jamesmoey/275faa6d58392fa742b6), you can implement your own class, based on Doctrine's ArrayCollection:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class ExtendedArrayCollection extends ArrayCollection
{
    /**
     * Reduce the collection into a single value.
     *
     * @param \Closure $func
     * @param null $initialValue
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function reduce(\Closure $func, $initialValue = null)
    {
        return array_reduce($this->toArray(), $func, $initialValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how the `ArrayCollection` class is described in the [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/1.6.4/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L28):

> An `ArrayCollection` is a `Collection` implementation that wraps a regular PHP array.

Its [`map()`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/1.6.4/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L320) method is just a wrapper of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) that returns a new `ArrayCollection` object that wraps the PHP array returned by `array_map()`.

Just to make everything clear, `array_map()` calls a function (its first argument) for each element of the array; the value returned by the function is stored in the resulting array.

For example:

```
$input  = [ 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, ];
$output = array_map(function ($x) { return $x * $x; }, $input);
print_r($output);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 4
    [three] => 9
)
```

`array_map()` can be invoked using one or more arrays (starting with its second argument). `ArrayCollection::map()` calls it using only one array (the one it wraps). When it's called with a single array, `array_map()` preserves its string keys (**but it re-numbers the numeric keys**).

---

**Revision:**

`ArrayCollection::map()` doesn't set keys or values. It applies a function to all the values stored in the collection and returns a new collection.

If you need to put a value at a specified key in an object of type `ArrayCollection`, you can use the regular PHP syntax to [access array elements using square brackets](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

The following code is equivalent with the code you posted in the question.

```
$arraycollection = new ArrayCollection();
$arraycollection[] = 'John Doe';
$arraycollection['foo'] = 'bar';
$arraycollection[418] = 'teapot';
```

The access using square brackets works because the [`ArrayCollection`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/1.6.4/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L40) class implements the [`Collection`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/1.6.4/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php#L32) interface that extends the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) PHP interface.

Answer (score 0):

> But you can't set keys with ArrayCollection::map().

Map is not a function to convert from a collection into a map.

In general map function operates on values from the list and is independent from the data structure so the behavior of ArrayCollection:map is quite natural.